# Why does this Gatsby starter not have a /src folder?

Tags: gatsby

I have installed this Gatbsy site locally:

https://www.gatsbyjs.org/starters/LekoArts/gatsby-starter-minimal-blog

with:

```
gatsby new gatsby2 https://github.com/LekoArts/gatsby-starter-minimal-blog
gatsby cd gatsby2
gatsby develop
```

and it displays fine and the site works as in the online demo.

However, now I want to use it as a basis for my own site and so am looking for the `/src` directory so I can change the code, as in other Gatsby starters (e.g. the Gatsby Starter Default site: `https://www.gatsbyjs.org/starters/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-default`).

I understood that all Gatsby sites have a `/src` directory, or is this not the case? And where is the code for this site? All I find is `/content` (markup files) and `static`:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The repository that you have provided introduces the concept of *shadowing* by Gatsby's themes. This is a feature that allows you to replace the `/src` folder with your own custom implementation. From [Gatsby documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/themes/shadowing/):

> Gatsby themes introduce a concept called “shadowing”. This feature
> allows users to replace a file in the `src` directory that is included
> in the webpack bundle with their own implementation. This works for
> React components, pages in `src/pages`, JSON files, TypeScript files, as
> well as any other imported file (such as `.css`) in your site.
>
> A practical use case is when you’ve installed `gatsby-theme-blog` and
> want to customize the author Bio component to add your own
> biographical content. Shadowing lets you replace the theme’s original
> file, `gatsby-theme-blog/src/components/bio.js`, with your own file to
> make any changes you need.

As you can see in [your dependencies](https://github.com/LekoArts/gatsby-starter-minimal-blog/blob/master/package.json#L19), the repository includes [`@lekoarts/gatsby-theme-minimal-blog`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@lekoarts/gatsby-theme-minimal-blog) where you can find all these shadowing configurations.

When shadowing, your ability to customize the structure is limited to the configuration of the shadow implementation itself, so, if you want to customize this starter, you should place your files into `/src/@lekoarts/gatsby-theme-minimal-blog/` to shadow/override files with your own structure. However, if you want to change the UI theme you should override the starter files by adding your own configuration under `/src/gatsby-plugin-theme-ui/` as you can see in the starter [`README.md`](https://github.com/LekoArts/gatsby-starter-minimal-blog#-using-and-modifying-this-starter).